# Get all rows form database where id=$id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, rows

Here is my code

```
 $this -> db -> select('*');
        $this -> db -> from('events');
        $this -> db -> where('user_id',$session_data['id']);


        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        $result = $query->result();

        if($result)
        {

            $events_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $events_array = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'title' => $row->title,
                    'ev_img_name' => $row->ev_img_name,

                );

                $this->session->set_userdata('events',$events_array);
            }
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('events');
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $data['id'] = $id;
            $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
            $title = $this->session->userdata('title');
            $data['title'] = $title;
            $data['title'] = $session_data['title'];
            $ev_img_name = $this->session->userdata('ev_img_name');
            $data['ev_img_name'] = $ev_img_name;
            $data['ev_img_name'] = $session_data['ev_img_name'];
```

It gets only the first row of the table, but i need to get all rows with same user_id . How can i do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: method `set_userdata` is inside the loop causing it to overwrite your data each iteration

Comment: Thanks, but how can i return all results?

Comment: why not just explicitly select specific columns, get the result set then assign it in your session, no need for loops

Comment: I'm new in coding. I'll try to explain what i need`

I have a table 'events' where users can add unlimited events.
Now I want to display the info of all of their events in their page.

Comment: Why saving all this data in session? that's a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the foreach you are reassigning the values to the same array.
Try using

```
 $events_array = array();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
      $events_array[] = array(
          'id' => $row->id,
          'title' => $row->title,
          'ev_img_name' => $row->ev_img_name,
      );

}
$this->session->set_userdata('events',$events_array);
```

This way you will have all the rows from the returned result in the `$events_array`.

Now in your view you can do this

```
<?php foreach($events_array as $event) { ?>
   <div class="event">
      Title: <?= $event['title'] ?>
      Image: <br>
      <img src="<?= $event['ev_img_name'] ?>">
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Then how will I put every result in variabales?

Comment: The result is in an array. You can just loop through it with a simple foreach. Could you please describe what you are trying to do. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm new in coding. I'll try to explain what i need` I have a table 'events' where users can add unlimited events. Now I want to display the info of all of their events in their page.

Comment: Although you do not need to use a loop at all, you could just do 
$this->db->select('id','title', 'ev_img_name')....
and then 
$events_array = $query->result_array();
and then pass that down to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code,
you can directly get the data whatever you want(number of fields) in array format from codeigniter sql query and than set that array directly to session as event like below,

```
 $this->db->select('id,title,ev_img_name');
 $this->db->from('events');
 $this->db->where('user_id',$session_data['id']);

 $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();

 if(count($result)>0){
      $this->session->set_userdata('events',$result);
 }
```

Comment: The problem is not with the query, the problem is with the loop. He is loosing the values there, by replacing them in every iteration.